# How to restrict some user on UNIX server for only accessing GIT command?

Tags: git, shell, unix, ssh

How to restrict User on UNIX server for only accessing GIT command? I want the users can only use the server to push/clone/pull from git repository that I have put in the server, but I dont want them to have ability to ssh or ftp to the server

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Answer (score 1):

Set their login shell to `/usr/bin/git-shell`:

```
sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/git-shell <username>
```

See http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-4.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

when a group of user had been created. use the chgrp command to change the group of /opt/apps/start to particular group:

```
# chgrp {groupName} {/path/to/command}
```

example

```
# chgrp newgroup /opt/apps/start
```

Disable the file permission for others

Finally, use the chmod command to change file permission as follows:

```
# chmod 750 /path/to/command
```

example

```
# chmod 750 /opt/apps/start
```

You can also apply permissions to directory (this will disable command access to others) :

```
# chgrp appsonly /opt/apps
# chmod 0640 /opt/apps
```

***Test***

su to usr1, enter:

```
# su - usr1
$ id
$ /opt/apps/start
$ exit
```

su to usr2(not a member of appsonly group), enter:

```
# su - usr2
$ id
$ /opt/apps/start
```

***Sample outputs:***

```
bash: /opt/apps/start: Permission denied
```

Refer below link for more details.... [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/protect-command-by-configuring-linux-unix-group-permissions/)